# Using a condition in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5

How can I rewrite this using a condition in LINQ?

If the selectID = zero, I want this to run :

```
   var products = from p in product.Table
       orderby p.Name
       where (p.stock == stockId)
      select p;
```

If the selectID NOT zero, I want this to run :

```
   var products = from p in product.Table
       orderby p.Name
       where (p.stock == stockId) &&        
             (p.Id == selectID)
      select p;
```

This below works, but I have to use a "dummy" second condition (p.hidden == false)
for the ternary operator to work :

```
   var products = from p in product.Table
       orderby p.Name
       where (p.stock == stockId) &&        
      (selectID != 0 ? p.Id == selectID : p.hidden == false)
      select p;
```

Is there a way to get rid of (p.hidden == false) because it is not required in the logic and is just there to get the operator to work. thanks

Comment: I would say that that @TimSchmelter's answer is technically totally correct, but if you ever get in the situation where you dynamically has to select / sort / filter properties plain `LINQ` might not always be the best solution. For example have a look at `dynamic LINQ` (just google it).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the same Id as the record as fallback value:

```
var products = from p in product.Table
               orderby p.Name
               where p.stock == stockId && 
                     p.Id == (selectID == 0 ? p.Id : selectID)
               select p;
```

However, since that could lead to a less efficient query plan i would simply use an `if-else`:

```
var products = product.Table.Where(p => p.stock == stockId);
if(selectID != 0)
    products = products.Where(p => p.Id == selectID);
products = products.OrderBy(p=> p.Name);
```

Comment: then there is no need of this condition just pass selectID

Comment: both worked great, thanks. Something I'm not understanding in the first query. If selectID = 0, then p.ID = p.ID. It still selects all records but I don't understand what "p.ID = p.ID" means?

Comment: @MikeHowe: it's just a fake condition, actually your selecting all records because everey record's `Id` value equals it's `Id` value. It's similar to `1=1`. So if `selectID == 0` the filter is redundant and might also be ignored by the query optimizer (however i'm not sure, hence my second approach).

Comment: I see it now. Thanks for the explanation Tim.

Answer (score 2):

You could also write it like this:

```
var products = from p in product.Table
       orderby p.Name
       where (p.stock == stockId) &&        
             (p.Id == selectID || selectID == 0)
      select p;
```

The `|| selectID == 0` just returns true if the ID isn't supplied and still allows the query to run as you intended.  The link below was how I learned this simple trick.

http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html

Comment: nice trick! I've used something similar with strings : (selectID == null || p.Id == selectID ) but this doesn't work well with int's or even nullable int's.

Comment: Whatever works :). For my knowledge, what problems have you had with this approach?

Comment: I meant my example, using null : (selectID == null || p.Id == selectID ) didn't work well with int's. Your example worked perfectly.